# How to establish what distribution to compare my statistic to

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, variance, mean

Apologies for this poorly titled question, but I've been taking some statistics courses and sometimes when you try to learn too many things in too little time you want to take a step back to check if you're actually understanding. I thought of the following:

*Suppose that you hire people to count the number of words in different Amazon reviews and report it back to you, and you want to check whether these people are doing their job instead of simply making the numbers up*.

Intuitively, you would take a sample of these reviews with their reported counts, you would count yourself, and you would compare the results. But what I want to know now is how exactly you would go about constructing a test that is mathematically valid.

My first thought was that I want to compare the reality to the hypothesis where every count is correct (in that case, the distribution of the average difference between my counts and their counts for a sample of n reviews would have an average of zero, since the numbers would have to match). And because this is a sample average, if I create a statistic by dividing the 'average difference' obtained in reality by the standard deviation and then by square root of n, I should be able to compare it to something like a normal distribution.

But then I thought that I don't know the variance of this hypothetical normal distribution (in fact, in my hypothesis where counts are perfect, it would be zero, which seems weird). And that has left me thinking that either some assumptions should be made about the underlying distribution, or some data would have to exist of 'average differences between reported counts and true counts' in order for me to have the parameters of the distribution that I want to compare my statistic to. The option of estimating the variance from the sample seems incorrect to me, as it is precisely the case that I don't know if the sample represents a world where my employees are doing their job and hence the counts are roughly ok.

I know it's all kind of vague, but could someone please enlighten me  (I'm asking specifically what would be the test, if any, for my example)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Javier. Perhaps "constructing a test that is mathematically valid" is not quite the right question to ask.  Rather than testing some (artificial) hypothesis, aren't you really interested in *how well people are performing their jobs?*  From this different perspective you would embark first on an *exploration* of the data, well before advancing any mathematical hypotheses for testing. Often, a single well-chosen statistical graphic will answer your questions--or at least suggest useful follow-on investigations.

Comment: @whuber Hi, thanks for the input, but in this case the question is completely hypothetical and its only purpose is to check my own understanding of how tests work and why and how we assume that statistics follow certain distributions, so I am hoping for a more literal answer : )

Comment: I gave you the literal answer: you should *always* start with exploration and you shouldn't ever suppose that a test is what you need to do.  Generally, though, this isn't a site for hypotheticals: it's aimed at addressing questions to real problems you actually have.  You can read about that somewhere in our [help] ;-).